# Div not moving down despite top

Tags: html, css

I'm sorry I tried everything, tried for thirty minutes couldn't get anything. Ok so this is my code. For some reason "div2" is not working and not moving down but ONLY able to move left and right. I want it to be able to move down and up from top or bottom of screen, but its only moving left and right and is located on the same level as the navbar

```
body {
   background-color: LightGoldenRodYellow;
   font-family:"Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
 }

 #rightcolumn {
  float: left;
 margin-left: 100px;
 }

#wrapper {
 background-color: #33CC00;
 color: #000066;
}

 #midcolumn {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;  
  Margin: 15px;
 }

 #leftcolumn {
 float: left;
 width: 100px;
 margin: 10px;
 }

 #footer {
    clear: both;
    position: relative;
     z-index: 10;
    height: 3em;
    margin-top: -3em;
}


  .navbar {
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 15px;
 display: block;
 }

 .div2{
 position:absolute;
 float: left;
 left: 200px;
 margin-top:100px:
 }


 .title{
 color: LightCoral;
 position:absolute;
 left: 50%;
 top: 10%;
 }

 .titlesub{
 color: Green;
 position:absolute;
 font-size: 12pt;   
 left: 50%;
 top; 30%;
 }


 .content{
 color: LightCoral;
 }
```

ok next file

```
<!doctype htm>

<html>

<head>
<link href="midterm_helper.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<title>Vacation Destination </title>

</head>


<body>

<h1 class="title">

Vacation Island

<p class="titlesub">

~vacation awaits!

</p>




</h1>

<p class="div2">
        test
        </p>



        <div>
            <a class="navbar" href="hotel_form.html" target="_blank">Reservations</a>

             <a class="navbar" href="hotel_room.html"         target="_blank">Rooms</a>

            </div>




















</body>

</html>
```

Comment: your html is not in well-form, the doc is incorrect... you probably want to remove the unwanted space characters in your future questions

Comment: unwanted...space characters? you mean all of the blank lines?

Comment: yes, it makes the html markup hard to read

Answer (score 6):

If any of you actually bothered to read his code, you'd see that he has a **colon:** after his top style instead of a **semi-colon;**

**This will do what you want it to do.  The float: left; isn't necessary though :)**

```
.div2 {
  position:absolute;
  float: left;
  left: 200px;
  margin-top:100px;
}
```

Comment: You're right `margin-top:100px:` instead of `margin-top:100px;`

Comment: I was saying what the OP did not what he should do. :)

Comment: Funny how you were the only one finding his mistake why he couldn't use margin-top and another answer gets credits =]. I gave you an upvote though

Answer (score 2):

To position the `div2` from bottom try this giving `bottom` value to the div

```
.div2{
    bottom:0; // change the value as you need
}
```

Comment: @Shinji-san please accept and close this if your problem is solved

Comment: @Shinji-san you can see a tick icon near all the answers. Click the one you found useful for your question. This is accepting the answer

Answer (score 0):

why you giving position and float at same time in class. If you used `position:absolute` then you may give the values to `top` `bottom` and `left` and `right`.

Also your HTML code is really messed up. remove unwanted space and first make it proper HTML.

For example you are giving position and floating the element at same time. you should use only one at one time.

```
.div2{
 position:absolute; /*either you should remove it*/
 float: left; /*or you should remove this line*/ 
 left: 200px;
 top:100px;
 left:0;
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can set `top` to move your div2 up and down like you have set by `left`

```
.div2{
top: 20px;    /*set the value depending upon your requirement */
}
```